# Kappa, AIC, user's and producer's accuracy from a confusion matrix

Tags: r

I have a confusion matrix, from which I would like to calulate the producer's and user's accuracy, and also get the overall Kappa and AIC value. I am aware that R has several packages that allow the calulation of Cohen's kappa statistic, however I cannot find any which handles a confusion matrix (or maybe I have not searched extensively enough). My confusion matrix is a 50 x 50 matrix, therefore manual calculation would be prone to error.

So for a sample of the matrix:

```
      V.1   V.2   V.3   V.4   V.5
V.1   10     0     2     1     0
V.2    1    12     0     0     0
V.3    0     0     9     4     0
V.4    0     2     0     11    3
V.5    4     1     0     0    11
```

Therefore, the User's accuracy for V.1 would be `(10/13)*100%`. Similarly, the Producer's for V.1 `(10/15)*100%`. I would have to`cbind` a new column for User's accuracy, and `rbind` a row for Producer's accuracy.  I assume I can use `melt` from the `reshape2` package to format the data in a table that can be used to calculate the kappa. But ideally I would like to keep the data in the confusion matrix format.

The ideal final result would look like:

```
      V.1   V.2   V.3   V.4   V.5  User Acc
V.1   10     0     2     1     0     76.92
V.2    1    12     0     0     0     92.30
V.3    0     0     9     4     0     69.23 
V.4    0     2     0     11    3     68.75 
V.5    4     1     0     0    11
Prod  66.66
```

kappa= Value, AIC = Value

Any pointers would be deeply appreciated

Comment: If you want to print your output in a certain way, write a function with `print`, `writeLines` or something similar. For help computing a statistic or finding a package to compute a statistic, then I think this is not the right place (though the stats stack exchange might help), since SO is for programming questions.

Comment: @ Frank, I already got my output in the form of the matrix presented. I thought I would have to write a function, but I could not figure out how to deal with the diagonal value. DWin has provided a too simplistic answer, but I did spend time and effort researching, before I posted the question here. I will be advised accordingly the next time. Thanks

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest you hadn't spent enough time researching. I meant the mention of `print`, etc. as a suggestion since your final result looks like less like a matrix than like some regression output (which you would have to customize yourself by writing to the console). I mentioned stats.SE because you insisted on talking about "confusion matrices" (instead of vanilla matrices), which I've never heard about and guess require some specialized knowledge... Fwiw, I didn't know about DWin's "`sos::findFn` strategy" either. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task of calculating those "accuracies" seems to be rather simple without using `melt`:

```
> diag(mat) /rowSums(mat)
      V.1       V.2       V.3       V.4       V.5 
0.7692308 0.9230769 0.6923077 0.6875000 0.6875000 
> diag(mat)/colSums(mat)
      V.1       V.2       V.3       V.4       V.5 
0.6666667 0.8000000 0.8181818 0.6875000 0.7857143
```

It may be even simpler than that since there seems to be package devoted to that processing:

```
require(sos)
findFn("kappa confusion matrix")
#found 38 matches;  retrieving 2 pages
#Downloaded 32 links in 16 packages.
```

See:   http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/PresenceAbsence/html/Kappa.html

I highly recommend the `sos::findFn` strategy.

```
maintainer('sos')
[1] "Spencer Graves <spencer.graves@prodsyse.com>"
```

Comment: Thanks DWin, I was completely unaware of these commands. I thought it could only be done by writing a specific function. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

An object of class Biclust

```
call:
        biclust(x = x, method = BCCC(), alpha = 1, delta = 1.5, number = 50)

Number of Clusters found:  31 

First  5  Cluster sizes:
                   BC 1 BC 2 BC 3 BC 4 BC 5
Number of Rows:      85   66   59   51   61
Number of Columns:   65   65   65   65   65
```

There are overlapping cols in the Biclusterresult
Warning message:
In `if (is.na(which)) which <- 1:ny` :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used